# Need an algorithm to calculate pi in parallel with pthreads in c

Tags: c, algorithm, parallel-processing, pthreads, pi

Before any rapid answer i would like to explain my needs. I'm working on a C-Posix project focused on parallel computing with Pthreads. I did my research, and i found dozens of algorithms to calculate Pi: Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula, Machin-like formula, Leibniz formula for π, Chudnovsky algorithm, monte-carlo, Ramanujan, etc.
The problem is that I don't need the "Best" algorithm in terms of speed convergence or digits per iteration, because obtaining pi is not the objective of the project *per se*. The real objective of the project is to compare the performance of the same programming problem solved both serial, and parallel with pthreads. 
For instance at the end of the project I’m expecting to get a comparative table like this:

[image]

After saying all of that i need an algorithm that is simple as it can be, simple to code in pthreads(not MPI, OpenMP, or similars)(Being embarrassingly parallel would be a perfect fit) and last but not least the algorithm must be suitable to show a great impact on parallelization

PD: i would also be greatful with anyone that can sugest any other parallel calculation that can fit to this project.

Thanks!

Comment: As for "other parallel calculation", just think of a program that needs to do a certain operation (pfff, like, string reversion?) on lots of input records.

Comment: Prime number calculation can be parallelized. Not for an individual number [not worth it], but you can do master/worker and have master keep feeding ranges (e.g. 2-1000 --> thread 0, 1000-2000 --> thread 1). When a thread completes its range, it asks master for a new range. Or, just have each thread calc it based on number of threads. But, then again, maybe parallel for an individual number might be interesting.

Comment: that sounds great. I will investigate about that types of algorithms while i wait for a response for this thread. Thanks.

Comment: Your table is flawed to begin with. You have to take in account it takes to create and delete the threads or your benchmarking is nonsense. Meaning cases like 10 or even 1000 iterations will likely be much slower in parallel.

Comment: Also, how about "vampire numbers". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834843/need-help-for-off-by-one-error-in-c-program-for-finding-factors See also: https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/3moxid/20150928_challenge_234_easy_vampire_numbers/ You can go much higher than the "4 2" and "6 3" orders and can even get into multiprecision math. Not as easy as it seems

Comment: yeah, you're right. I will need to take that in account when defining the metrics to compare the performance. The table was just an example of the behaviour i'm expecting to find in general.

Comment: @Lundin Given that his table has 10 trillion iterations being done in serial in about a second, I think the OP was just making up numbers as an example.

Comment: How about mergesort? Batcher algorithm?

Comment: @Chris Yes of course he is, but the made-up numbers suggest he has unrealistic expectations of when parallel processing is efficient and when it is not. It is not some universal cure against all poor performance.

Comment: @Lundin I suppose. They look a little *too* ridiculous though. Like a factor of 200 speedup with 10 threads for 10 iterations :)

Comment: Don't put too much on it, i just hit almost random numbers on the keyboard. I was just trying to explain that i was looking for a time improvement compared to a serial method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Monte Carlo method to approximate pi (to arbitrary precision) is easily parallelizable. In pseudocode:

```
total=0;
inside=0;
while(total<whatever) {
    double1=random(0,1); //Random number from zero to 1
    double2=random(0,1);
    total++;
    if(double1**2 + double2**2 < 1) {inside++;}
}
pi=4*inside/total;
```

Everything inside the loop can be parallelized on as many threads as you like, and you just have to add up the results at the end.

Edit: As caf mentions in the comments, it's important that the RNGs are independent for each thread or you will get no improvement from running multiple threads.

Comment: So asuming 10000 iterations and a thread pool of 10, could a thread look like simply like this:

for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
    double1=random(0,1); //Random number from zero to 1
    double2=random(0,1);
    ptotal++;
    if(double1* * 2 + double2* * 2 < 1) {pinside++;}
}

total = total + ptotal;
inside = inside + pinside;

(sorry i can't indent in the comments)

Comment: @holyknight Looks about right to me.

Comment: @holyknight By the way, you can still mark something as code with backticks (i.e. \`) `code`

Comment: Great, will try this.
PD: i do plenty of reading at stackoverflow but i'm still not used to the platform :D

Comment: One potential pitfall to avoid with parallelised Monte-Carlo methods is that you need to ensure you're using per-thread PRNGs for the random numbers.

Comment: @caf Important point I forgot to mention. I'll put that in the answer.

Comment: i'm getting only 4 correct digits with 1000000000 iterations. Is that slow the convergence rate of this method?

Comment: That sounds about right. The relative error scales generally as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. Definitely not the best for solving for pi quickly, but it fits your use case.

Comment: Yeah i was only wondering that, and by the way thanks. I already set the answer as correct.